# Php regex to validate multiple occurence of input

Tags: php, regex, validation

What's the regex for validating input for this

Below 3 line are valid

```
PROJ9450
PROJ9400-PROJ9401-PROJ9402 ..... PROJ{n}
PROJ9400_1-PROJ9400_2-PROJ9401_1-PROJ9402_1-PROJ9408 ... PROJ{n}_{n}
```

Below lines are Invalid strings

```
PROJ450
PRO1223
PROJ9400a-PROJ9401-PROJ9400-PROJ1929-1-PROJ1929
PROJ9400_1-PROJ9400_2-PROJ9401_1-PROJ9402_1-PROJs453 ... PROJ{n}_{n}
```

I tried this

```
if( preg_match('/(PROJ)[0-9]{4}(-|_)?[0-9]+)/', $input) )
{

}
```

I can split and can validate like something like below , but I want to do this by single regex

```
 foreach(explode('-',$input) as $e)
 {
        if( !preg_match('/(PROJ)[0-9]{4}(-|_)?[0-9]+)/', $e) )
        {
             return 'Invalid Input';
        }
 }
```

> Input can be just prefixed by PROJ and 4 digit number
>
> PROJ9450

OR

> Input can be prefixed by PROJ and 4 digit number - prefixed by PROJ and
>   4 digit number like this upto `n`
>
> PROJ9400-PROJ9401-PROJ9402 ..... PROJ{n}

OR

> Input can be prefixed by PROJ and 4 digit number undescore digit -
>   prefixed by PROJ and 4 digit number underscore digit like this upto
>   `n`
>
> PROJ9400_1-PROJ9400_2-PROJ9401_1-PROJ9402_1 ... PROJ{n}_{n}

Comment: You should also show several invalid strings (and explain why).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to match the block starting with `PROJ` and followed with 4 digits (that are optionally followed with `-` or `_` and 1+ digits) *repeatedly*.

Use

```
/^(PROJ[0-9]{4}(?:[-_][0-9]+)?)(?:-(?1))*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MHUBfi/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string [**anchor**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `(PROJ[0-9]{4}(?:[-_][0-9]+)?)` - Group 1 (that will be later recursed with `(?1)` [**recursion construct**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html)) capturing:

  - `PROJ` - a literal char sequence
  - `[0-9]{4}` - 4 digits
  - `(?:[-_][0-9]+)?` - an optional (1 or 0 occurrences) of

    - `[-_]` - a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matching `-` or `_`
    - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:-(?1))*` - zero or more occurrences of `-` followed with Group 1 subpattern up to...
- `$` - end of string (better replace it with `\z` anchor that matches the very end of the string).

Comment: Wow.. this is awesome... this is what I wanted recursion based.. Thank you so much

Comment: PROJ9450-1 should be false

Comment: Why should it be false? You should add it to the list of invalid inputs. Try [`^(?!PROJ\d{4}[-_]\d+$)(PROJ\d{4}(?:[-_]\d+)?)(?:-(?1))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/MHUBfi/3). The `(?!PROJ\d{4}[-_]\d+$)` lookahead will fail all the strings similar to `PROJ1234-12` or `PROJ1234_12`.